# FatalError with RequestContext constructor

Tags: caching, symfony4

I have a problem with an update of a Symfony 4 project, I get a fatal error:

```
"Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Routing\RequestContext::__construct() must be of the type string, null given, called in var/cache/dev/ContainerHuVphBe/srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php on line 1569"
```

Has anyone ever had a similar problem? It's impossible for me to find where this configuration error came from.

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: did you try to remove cache? if not, remove var/cache folder

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for your reply, I have already flushed the cache many times, including completely deleting the directories but nothing worked.

Comment: Hello,

Does anyone have an idea to fix this problem?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Had this problem updating from Symfony 3 to Symfony 4, found the fix to be changing out configuration files.

Before:

```yaml
router.request_context.base_url: ~
```

After:

```yaml
router.request_context.base_url: ""
```